# Set position of UIToolbar in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface

I'm having trouble getting a UIToolbar to appear at the bottom of the screen when my app loads. Regardless of how I position the UIToolbar and regardless of the constraints that I have put on the bar, it always appears in the middle of the screen. I have my navigation bar situated correctly, and I've never had trouble situating UI elements in IB before (although I'm new to iOS programming). Any ideas on how to make sure the toolbar stays in place? Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried changing the simulator device to no avail.

Comment: in Xcode 7b4, turn off auto layout.

Comment: are you adding toolbar programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not playing the game correctly with UINavigationController. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

> Displaying a Navigation Toolbar
>
> A navigation controller object manages
>   an optional toolbar in its view hierarchy. When displayed, this
>   toolbar obtains its current set of items from the toolbarItems
>   property of the active view controller. When the active view
>   controller changes, the navigation controller updates the toolbar
>   items to match the new view controller, animating the new items into
>   position when appropriate.
>
> The navigation toolbar is hidden by default but you can show it for
>   your navigation interface by calling the setToolbarHidden:animated:
>   method of your navigation controller object. If not all of your view
>   controllers support toolbar items, your delegate object can call this
>   method to toggle the visibility of the toolbar during subsequent push
>   and pop operations. To use a custom UIToolbar subclass, use the
>   initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass: method to initialize the
>   navigation controller.

**EDIT** to include answer to question in comments:

No code needs to be written to do all this. You can set "Shows Toolbar" in the Attributes Inspector of your Navigation VC. You can then drag individual `UIBarButtonItem`s onto particular VCs (on which a toolbar will suddenly appear) and do the usual outlets and actions with them.

Comment: Great, I can now see the toolbar in the correct location at the bottom of the screen using this method. But now I must add bar button items to this toolbar programmatically instead of in interface builder? Is there any way to go about situating the toolbar so that I may perform subsequent operations in IB? @BaseZen